# Search Users within Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

In my C# application I am trying to search for a User via Graph API. The only parameter I have is the username which is stored in onPremisesSamAccountName field.

Through Graph Explorer I can successfully run the query

[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$count=true&$search="onPremisesSamAccountName:myusername"&$select=id,displayName](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$count=true&$search=%22onPremisesSamAccountName:myusername%22&$select=id,displayName)

And Graph Explorer gives me the C# code to use

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

var users = await graphClient.Users
    .Request()
    .Search("onPremisesSamAccountName:myusername")
    .Select("id,displayName")
    .GetAsync();
```

Now when I try to use that code I get an error saying that Search is not a method, do I need to add an extra package to use Search?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I also didn't find any nuget package with `Search` method.

You can specify search value by using query option. $search query parameter requires a request header ConsistencyLevel: eventual

```
var queryOptions = new List<Option>()
        {
            new QueryOption("$search", "\"onPremisesSamAccountName:myusername\""),
            new HeaderOption("ConsistencyLevel", "eventual")
        };
        var users = await graphClient.Users
            .Request(queryOptions)
            .Select("id,displayName")
            .GetAsync();
```

Comment: Thanks. I've just tried that but I get an error. 

Code: BadRequest
Message: Syntax error: character ':' is not valid at position 24 in 'onPremisesSamAccountName:username'.

Comment: With it set as new QueryOption("$search", "\"onPremisesSamAccountName:username\"")  it seems to work but I get an error Message: Request with $search query parameter only works through MSGraph with a special request header: 'ConsistencyLevel: eventual'

Comment: @Dave I've updated the answer and add ConsistencyLevel header